# Реферальная ссылка через бота автораспределения

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, python-telegram-bot

***Доброго времени суток!***

Возник очень интересный вопрос как мне создать реферальную ссылку на заход в бота, где человек переходящий в общего бота распределителя и нажав кнопку "получения личного бота", сразу перешел по нему и оказался там сразу по рефу(твоему)  а не вводя ее в поле ввода, через несколько шагов) возможно ли как-то это реализовать?

А то приходится чуть ли не насильно капсом всех в бота вступить заставлять, ввидя допустим мой реф код - "jtefh", я ведь за это тоже бонус получу, друг, прям как и ты!)

Comment: Если возникнут вопросы - пишите их под ответом, чтобы мне пришли уведомления. Если все ок и ответ помог вам, то можете поставить галочку слева от ответа. См. справку [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: все получилось?

Answer (score 0):

Для этого используют механизм Deep Linking

https://core.telegram.org/bots#deep-linking

Вы можете передать в ссылке параметр `start`

https://t.me/my_awesome_bot?start=jtefh

И перехватить его при обработке команды старт.
В данном случае вам придет сообщение

```
/start jtefh
```

> **Замечание:**
> Вы не можете передавать произвольные параметры в бот. 
> Доступны только два варианта `start` и `startgroup`
> *При использовании `startgroup` пользователь сначала должен будет добавить бота в группу*

Обработать его можно следующим образом

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')


def extract_referral_code(text):
    # Извлекает код присланный в команде start
    return text.split()[1] if len(text.split()) > 1 else None

# обрабатываем команду старт
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    # получаем реферальный код
    referral_code = extract_referral_code(message.text)
    if referral_code:  # если команда '/start' содержала реферальный код  
        # обработка реферального кода
        # ...
    else:
        # обработка обычного сообщения
        # ...
    bot.reply_to(message, reply)


bot.infinity_polling()
```

Comment: А если от лица покупателя брать? Это во всех магазинах сразу работает? Или все же надо настраивать такие переходы и "ссылка для подписчиков" мягко говоря может не сработать?

Comment: О каких магазинах речь?... Если это бот ваш, если вы релизовали вышестоящий обработчик в боте и если пользователь перешел по ссылке с параметром, то все обработается.

Comment: @Ярослав вы хотите чтобы эта ссылка обрабатывалась в ботах к которым вы не имеете отношения?

Comment: Да я все верно + интерпретировать в своего бота)

Comment: @Ярослав, если вы в своем боте это реализуете, то вы сможете учитывать рефералы указанным в ответе способом при переходе по ссылкам с параметром, который я указал в ответе... все что вам нужно сделать это добавить соотвествующую обработку реферального кода.